# How to modify svg path from and to attributes in IE

Tags: javascript, svg

I use follow code fragment to modify a svg path object

```
el.setAttribute("from", start[0] + "," + start[1]);
var path = line.childNodes[0];
path.setAttribute("d", "M " + start[0] + " " + start[1] + " L " + end[0] + " " + end[1]);
```

It works well in ff and chrome, but in IE, it doesn't work. I see the DOM structure in F12 panel, the attributes was modified, but the change doesn't show in explorer, how can I change the attributes in IE and affect the explorer?

Thanks

Comment: What version of IE are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to create/parse svg paths with string values, as you have seen, can be a problem. It is best to use svg's **pathSegList** object when building/editing paths, rather than strings. It works across all browsers.